# Angular buffer events and then after an inactivity delay do something

Tags: angular, rxjs

I was looking for an angular style way of implementing the following.

At some point an event will start spamming. I want to catch all those calls and after it stopped spamming (defined by some time interval, e.g. no calls for 1s) I want to get notified and call a function. I'm not interested in the results of the events, just in the notification that there has been no occurence for e.g. 1s.

If it starts spamming again the procedure should start again.

I have looked into buffers for observables but found nothing that would fit the case, most of those buffer events until a condition is met (timout reached, variable set).

I know I could implement this by resetting a timer each time the event occurs and the throwing an event when the timer reaches the interval I'm interested in.

I had the feeling that there would be a more elegant way to achieve this with rxjs/angular, that I am not seeing.

Comment: Is `auditTime()` operator what you're looking for?

Comment: @martin if I understood auditTime correctly, it's not what I'm looking for. auditTime will ignore a source for a fixed amount of time. I want to ignore my source for an indefinite amount of time (as long as it is emitting) until it didn't emit for a fixed amount of time. In the documentation it says something interesting about the interaction with debounce though....

Comment: Then maybe `debounceTime`

Comment: @martin debounceTime is meant to space out events so that you only get them after a fixed amount of time, all events are buffered and then sent

Comment: I think I don't understand what you want to do then

Answer (score 0):

You can use the event spam to reset a Subject

```
export class Q52775767Component {
  private resetSubject$ = new Subject();

  constructor() {
    // first event spammer
    timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(take(10))
      .subscribe(next => {
        console.log('event spammer ' + next);
        this.resetSubject$.next(void 0);
      });

    // second event spammer starts after 15 seconds
    timer(15000, 1000).subscribe(next => {
      console.log('event spammer 2 ' + next);
      this.resetSubject$.next(void 0);
    });

    // This subject emits if no "spam" was received
    this.resetSubject$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(() => timer(2000, 1000)) // wait for a two seconds "hole" then emit each second
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.targetFunction());
  }

  targetFunction() {
    console.log('Target reached');
  }
}
```